# Autoplay fullscreen video not working. Not sure what the issue is

Tags: javascript

So I've been working on a homepage website for a decent amount of time now. Most things are fairly basic, but I am trying to input a script that randomly plays a video from a certain playlist once on.

This is what I have, I have messed around with this for a good couple of hours but haven't seemed to make any sort of progress.

```js
var videos = [
    'D1sZ_vwqwcE',
    'yx2piPUudlE',
    'BC_Ya4cY8RQ'
];

var index=Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
var html='<div class="video-background"><div class="video-foreground"><iframe frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' +[index] + '?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;></iframe></div></div>';
document.write(html);
```

```html
<html class=""><head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Zenith</title>
  
  
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

  
<style id="__web-inspector-hide-shortcut-style__" type="text/css">
.__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__, .__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__ *, .__web-inspector-hidebefore-shortcut__::before, .__web-inspector-hideafter-shortcut__::after
{
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
</style></head>

<body>
  
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class="glitch">Zenith</h1>
</div>

   
  <a class="glitch-btn" href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/1zv" target="_blank">
  <div class="label">Steam</div>
  <div class="mask"><span>Steam</span></div>
  <div class="mask"><span>Steam</span></div>
  <div class="mask"><span>Steam</span></div>
  <div class="mask"><span>Steam</span></div>
  <div class="mask"><span>Steam</span></div></a>
  
  <a class="glitch-btn1" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwBh4mBv-QrIynWxCj-8AVw" target="_blank">
  <div class="label">Youtube</div>
  <div class="mask"><span>Youtube</span></div>
  <div class="mask"><span>Youtube</span></div>
  <div class="mask"><span>Youtube</span></div>
  <div class="mask"><span>Youtube</span></div>
  <div class="mask"><span>Youtube</span></div></a>
    
    <script src="assets/javascript/script.js"></script>  


</body></html>
```

Now I'm not certain if it's because I am using a free host / codepen to mess around, or something is just wrong.

(I also have css but trying to copy it here exceeded the character limit)

Comment: your code? where is it **¯\\(°_o)/¯**

Comment: some sort of...

Comment: sorry. clicked enter by accident. Edited the post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left out a closing quote from the `html` variable. Also, you're referencing the id wrong.

```
var html='<div class="video-background"><div class="video-foreground"><iframe frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videos[index] + '?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;"></iframe></div></div>';
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct, since it helped you out and all